# Creating a jQuery vertical scroll loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scroll

I'm trying to write a jQuery script that will continually scroll these `<p>` tags within their `<div>` parent. I got the idea from [this site](http://rdbk.tv/).

```js
function shuffle(){

    $('#wrapper > p').each(function(){
        h = ($(this).offset().top + 130);
        if( h > 500 ){
            console.log(h);
            $(this).css ('top', 0 );
            return;
        }

        if( h == 270 ){
            $(this).addClass('current' );
        }

        if( h == 360 ){
            $(this).removeClass('current' );
        }
        
        $(this).animate({
            top: h,
            easing: 'easeIn'
        }, 500, '');
        
        if( h > 1350 ){
            $(this).css ('top', 0 );
        }
    });

    window.setTimeout(shuffle, 2500);
}

var i = 0;
        
$('#wrapper > p').each(function(){
    starter = $(this).css('top', ((i * 90) ) + 'px' );
    starterWhite = ($(this).offset().top + 130);
    if((i*90) == 270)
        $(this).addClass('current');
    $(this).css('top', starter );
    i++;
});

window.setTimeout(shuffle, 2000);
```

```css
#wrapper {
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

p {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.current {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>7</p>
</div>
```

Problem is when I try to make it scroll the `<p>` tags overlap, and the highlighted tag doesn't change. Any idea how to make it work? [Here's a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LLfrq3xv/) of what I got so far.

Comment: Also the JSFiddle I created is based mostly off the code from his [.js file here](http://rdbk.tv/js/portfolio.js).

Comment: Did you see my answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check [this](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/4ndoy8ee/6/) out:

```js
// Constants, you can play with it
var STEP = 90;
var CURRENT_INDEX = 3;

// Variables for calculating
var currentTop = STEP * CURRENT_INDEX;
var nextForCurrentTop = STEP * (CURRENT_INDEX + 1);
var $numbers = $('#wrapper > p');
// In this case = 7
var count = $numbers.length;
var secondToLastTop = STEP * (count - 1);

$numbers.each(function(i) {
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.css('top', i * STEP + 'px');

    if (i === CURRENT_INDEX) {
        $this.addClass('current');
    }
});

window.setTimeout(shuffle, 2000);

function shuffle() {
    $numbers.each(function() {
        $this = $(this);
        // Calculating the new position of the element
        h = parseInt($this.css('top')) + STEP;

        // In this case = 540
        if (h > secondToLastTop) {
            $this.css('top', 0);
            return;
        }

        // In this case visually = 3rd element
        if (h === currentTop) {
            $this.addClass('current');
        }

        // In this case visually = 4th element
        if (h === nextForCurrentTop) {
            $this.removeClass('current');
        }

        $this.animate({
            top: h,
            easing: 'easeIn'
        }, 500, '');
    });

    window.setTimeout(shuffle, 2500);
}
```

```css
#wrapper {
    height: 500px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}

p {
    position: absolute;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.current {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>6</p>
    <p>7</p>
</div>
```

I improved and commented code from your example, removed magic numbers. You can play with constants.

Comment: Yeah that's the problem, but now he knows that those numbers are hardcoded so he can modify them to his needs :)

Comment: Thanks for this! I'm trying to incorporate this code into my actual website and i'm still having the stacking problem. How were you able to find out which values were needed? For example line 3 or 5 in the javascript.

Comment: @Sosa I improved/simplified/commented my code, check this out now.

Comment: Thank you so much it worked perfectly! Really appreciate you putting the time to edit the code and write those comments. It also works on my other website so there is no more of that stacking. Really man, good job.

Comment: This is great, but how do you get it to go UP (1,2,3, etc.) instead of DOWN?

Comment: In other words, I'm getting 1, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1 and would like 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7...Here's my Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7fmf5buq/24/

Comment: @rjbullock I think you should create another question for it.